# BASH script to count LOC

Tags: bash, scripting, cygwin

In all my source code files, I have a "header" of information at the top of each file that looks like this (example in Java):

```
/* Project: UVa Online Judge
 * Filetype: Java Source Code File
 * Filename: generic.java
 * Path: compsci/sandbox/uva_online_judge
 * Filesize: 1275 bytes
 * Date Created: 11/17/2011
 * Last Modified: Tue Nov 20, 2012  02:28PM
 * LOC: 33
 */
```

From a BASH command line (I'm using GNU bash version 4.1.10 on Cygwin version 1.7.16) I'm trying to calculate total LOC (lines of code) for all my source files in a particular project folder. I'm going to the top level project folder (some of my source code is in subfolders of this folder) and running the following:

```
$ grep -r LOC: *
```

which gives me the following:

```
generic.c: * LOC: 44
generic.java: * LOC: 33
solved/100/uva_100.java: * LOC: 77
solved/102/uva_102.java: * LOC: 139
solved/108/uva_108.c: * LOC: 94
solved/120/uva_120.java: * LOC: 109
solved/200/uva_200.java: * LOC: 83
solved/414/uva_414.c: * LOC: 61
solved/424/uva_424.c: * LOC: 100
solved/700/uva_700.c: * LOC: 108
solved/900/uva_900.java: * LOC: 54
unsolved/341/uva_341.java: * LOC: 349
```

But I'd like to modify that bash script to actually calculate the total LOC, given the output above it would be 1251.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: not answering your question, but it sounds like [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) could be useful in your situation

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it with `awk`:

```
grep -r LOC: * | awk '{sum+=$NF} END{print sum}'
```

**Explanation:**

- `grep -r LOC: *` - your question already shows what this does
- `|` pipes the results from the grep in previous step to the next command
- `awk` invokes the awk tool
- `{sum+=$NF}`: for each line, add the very last field to `sum`. `NF` stands for Number of Fields in awk, so `$NF` is the content of the field with that number.
- `END{print sum}`: after all lines have been parsed, print the sum

Comment: Much more concise solution and better explanation than my own answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use awk:

```
grep -r LOC: * | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$4}END{print sum}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
bc <<< $(tr ' ' '+' <<< $(grep -r '^ *\* *LOC:' | cut -d ' ' -f4))
```

or this

```
c=0
grep -r '^ *\* *LOC:' | cut -d ' ' -f4 | while read a; do
    ((c+=$a))
done

echo "$c lines"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cute trick by setting $IFS:

```
total=$(set -- $(grep -hoP '(?<=LOC: )\d+' *); IFS=+; bc <<< "$*")
```

Assuming cygwin has GNU grep